# How to remove a plugin in Django CMS?

Tags: django, django-cms

I have registered my plugin using the code

```html
@plugin_pool.register_plugin
class FAQPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = FAQ
    name = "FAQ"
    render_template = "plugins/faq.html"
    cache = False
    allow_children = True
    require_parent = False

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context = super().render(context, instance, placeholder)
        return context
```

However, when I decide to remove the plugin from code though it's not used on a page anymore, I have an error:

```html
KeyError at /en/product/

'FAQPlugin'
```

Comment: You should run `manage.py cms check`. There's a good change the `delete-orphaned-plugins` command will help you. Essentially you need to remove plugins from the database before you remove them from the code. https://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/reference/cli.html#cms-delete-orphaned-plugins

Comment: Try this command  `cms uninstall plugins <plugin name> `